# untrusted executable "ln", should it be removed, if yes how?

Tags: internet-security, exec, macos-ventura

I was inspecting the startup items to disabled non utilized applications and came across this item from unidentified developer.

What should I do about it? And how to proceed if is to be removed?

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)? What's your actual goal here and why? This question is quite XY problem looking.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the wiki link. i honestly was concerned about the unidentified developer part, but that seems to be an integral part of the OS functionality.

Comment: Ok, but why? I understand when people are keeping an eye on security, but it seems to be purposeless in this case. On my system(s) I have and had a bunch of apps throwing "Unkown publisher' kind of warnings, but a virus only got me once - for a short moment just because I was downloading and testing a bunch of torrents at that time.

Comment: @Destroy666 yes, it did answer it. I realized that it is an OS component to say, but the not trusted publisher part bothered me. Can that file be corrupted, even exchanged to a malicious file with the same name, why an OS component ha a unidentified publisher?

Comment: If the system doesn't let you delete it with `sudo` priviledge, you'd need to have a very very serious and much more noticable breach for the replacement to be possible in the 1st place. Why does the file have no developer assigned? I don't know, that's more of opinion-based question, unless answered by the people who decided to not give it that metadata. Perhaps it's related to the fact that it's Unix. Seems like more Unix commands have this in common in macOS:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/454893/what-is-the-open-unix-script-for-and-why-is-it-unidentified

Comment: And here you have an answer why `ln` is in startup (which was the only a bit weird thing for me here): https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453503/why-do-i-see-ln-listed-in-the-login-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ln` is a [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)) Unix command related to creating symlinks and hard links to your files and directories. It's included in macOS by default. There is no purpose of deleting it. Doing that could even potentially result in problems with apps that utilize it within their code or installation processes. **So I definitely wouldn't recommend trying it**.

As for why `ln` is listed in startup, which is the only bit unusual/weird thing here, check [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451999/macos-ventura-13-1-bin-ln-can-run-in-background/452090#452090).

This method of checking random executables is not really a way to secure your system. You should rather be careful when downloading and installing software by e.g. using only trusted sources - that's the most safe way to avoid infections if you learn how to spot potential danger. On top of that you can use antivirus that can detect most of the threats that you miss.